# Java code compression and decompression of a string

Tags: java, string, compression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Write a simple JAVA program to compress a string and decompress the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373078/write-a-simple-java-program-to-compress-a-string-and-decompress-the-string)

I am having a problem figuring how to check a string for the same characters in a row then count that same character in a row then printing it out then giving the location of the last occorance of that character count then printing it out then moving to the next character in the string that is different then the previous character and the program is case sensitive.

So the input could be: aaaaAAAbbbddccc

How would I compress this string to: a4A3b3d2c3 ? and then decompress it?

Comment: Having trouble or expecting someone to do it for you? What have you actually tried?

Comment: Your other question has been alredy closed as it was the same. Try to learn from experience as every living being does.

Comment: Start with a `for-loop` and [`String#charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) and see where it takes you

Comment: unless you provide some code you came up with while attempting to solve this, you're going to get little help and down-voted since this sounds like a homework question...

Answer (score 1):

**No one is here to do your homework So please show some effort before asking question**
 
AnyWay You just need to chk char at every index of String and then after counting add it to the next. `String.charAt(indexNumber)` method an help you for this :)
here is example code for you

```
        String orginalString = "AAAaaaBBBbbb",
        compressedString = "";

        String found =Character.toString(orginalString.charAt(0));
        int counter = 0;
        for(int a=1;a<orginalString.length();a++){


            if(found.equals(Character.toString(orginalString.charAt(a))))
            {
                counter++;
            }
            else{

                compressedString = compressedString+(found+counter);
                counter =0;
                found = Character.toString(orginalString.charAt(a));
                a--;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Here is you compressed String"+compressedString );
}
```